# Assembler debugging to get system time

Tags: assembly, dosbox

I am attempting to try to get the system date for my PC with the DOS function AH = 2A.  As you can see from the picture below, I'm having a bit of an issue getting DH, DL and AL.  CX comes up when I run it and I'm able to get the year 2017.

[image: Picture of DOSBOX]

Comment: I don't think `int 21` has been executed yet, that picture tells us nothing. What's in `DX` **after** it has executed?

Comment: well, I added int 21 on line 102 to run.  but it looks like it gets to line 102 and halts.

Comment: `p` executes a loop, a repeated string instruction, a software interrupt, or a subroutine. So after assembling the 2 instructions, `p` executed the `mov ah, 2a` and showed the register dump. the last line is the instruction ready to be executed next, not the last instruction executed. Do another `p` to do the `int 21`

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more detail about what the problem is. I tried your little program and it worked for me: CX=07E1 (2017), DX=011D (Jan 29), AL=0 (Sun). Did you actually execute the int 21? In your dosbox it looks like you stopped before it even executed.

[picture of my dosbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACTCp.png)

Comment: how are you getting Jan 29 from DX=011D

Comment: DH=01=January, DL = 1D (hex) = 29 (decimal)

Comment: no he didn't. the INT 21 debug shows is the NEXT instruction, so DX/CX shown is the values before the call